# como interactuar con el objeto de la extensión desde un MouseListener?

Tags: kotlin, mouselistener

Tengo problemas para establecer el background del jbutton que llame a esta extensión de código a través del evento MouseEntered de MouseListener.

```
fun JButton.setProperties(/* My arguments */) {
    /*My code*/

    this.addMouseListener(object : MouseListener {
        override fun mouseClicked(e: MouseEvent) {
        }

        override fun mousePressed(e: MouseEvent) {
        }

        override fun mouseReleased(e: MouseEvent) {
        }

        override fun mouseEntered(e: MouseEvent) {
            parent.this.background = semiDarkGrayBlue
        }

        override fun mouseExited(e: MouseEvent) {
        }
    })
}
```

si retiro `parent.` reconoce al objeto MouseListener en lugar de mi JButton.
este `parent.` es solo una palabra para mostrar la idea, realmente no funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para acceder al this de la extensión setProperties en lugar del this del objeto MouseListener, usamos una anotación que especifica a cuál this estamos haciendo referencia, en este caso, al this de la extensión setProperties, por lo tanto escribimos el siguiente código:

```
    override fun mouseEntered(e: MouseEvent) {
        this@setProperties.background = semiDarkGrayBlue
    }
```

El this por defecto es el más interno, en este caso el del objeto MouseListener

Comment: Revisa [answer], para la misma no sea reportada como de baja calidad.

Comment: Qué tal ahí?, gracias por la sugerencia !

Comment: Además de la explicación, si tú mismo ya has conseguido la respuesta, márcala como aceptada. Eso te reportará puntos que son necesarios para, por ejemplo poder comentar en cualquier publicación.